# Uploading and running an ASP.NET MVC 5 site with Identity causes strange DB behavior

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I've created an ASP.NET MVC 5 website with the OOB authentication functionality (Individual accounts).

Everything has been running fine on my dev PC and now it's time to publish the thing.

The web host that the site needs to sit on isn't my choice, but hey ho. I need to upload the files via FTP and do the DB migration via some HTML based admin console "MyLittleAdmin".

I've exported all the schemas for all the tables and SP's and imported them on the web hosts SQL server.

However, if I try running the site and register myself as a new user all I get is a quite lengthy error message stating:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'. at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError

What I don't get is why it's trying to create the database from scratch, since it's a shared server I don't have permissions to go ahead and create my own DB's, but I have specified the existing DB in the Connection string in the web.config.

Here's the complete stack trace:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'. at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String methodName, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.<>c.<NonQuery>b__4_0(DbCommand t, DbCommandInterceptionContext`1 c) at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext,TResult](TTarget target, Func`3 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed) at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.NonQuery(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext interceptionContext) at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.<>c__DisplayClass52_0.b__0(DbConnection conn) at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.<>c__DisplayClass60_0.b__0() at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.b__0() at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation) at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute(Action operation) at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.UsingConnection(DbConnection sqlConnection, Action`1 act) at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.UsingMasterConnection(DbConnection sqlConnection, Action`1 act) at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.CreateDatabaseFromScript(Nullable`1 commandTimeout, DbConnection sqlConnection, String createDatabaseScript) at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.DbCreateDatabase(DbConnection connection, Nullable`1 commandTimeout, StoreItemCollection storeItemCollection) at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices.CreateDatabase(DbConnection connection, Nullable`1 commandTimeout, StoreItemCollection storeItemCollection) at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.CreateDatabase() at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Utilities.DatabaseCreator.Create(DbConnection connection) at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action mustSucceedToKeepDatabase) at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Update(String targetMigration) at System.Data.Entity.Internal.DatabaseCreator.CreateDatabase(InternalContext internalContext, Func`3 createMigrator, ObjectContext objectContext) at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.CreateDatabase(ObjectContext objectContext, DatabaseExistenceState existenceState) at System.Data.Entity.Database.Create(DatabaseExistenceState existenceState) at System.Data.Entity.CreateDatabaseIfNotExists`1.InitializeDatabase(TContext context) at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.<>c__DisplayClass66_0`1.<CreateInitializationAction>b__0() at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformInitializationAction(Action action) at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformDatabaseInitialization() at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.<>c.<InitializeDatabase>b__58_0(InternalContext c) at System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryAction`1.PerformAction(TInput input) at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabaseAction(Action`1 action) at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabase() at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.Initialize() at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType) at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize() at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext() at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Linq.IQueryable.get_Provider() at System.Data.Entity.QueryableExtensions.FirstOrDefaultAsync[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at System.Data.Entity.QueryableExtensions.FirstOrDefaultAsync[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate) at Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.UserStore`6.<GetUserAggregateAsync>d__67.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.TaskExtensions.CultureAwaiter`1.GetResult() at Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.UserValidator`2.<ValidateUserName>d__14.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.UserValidator`2.d__13.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.UserManager`2.<CreateAsync>d__73.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.UserManager`2.d__79.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() at PadelTour_Prod.Controllers.AccountController.<Register>d__16.MoveNext() in C:\NonOS\DevLib\PrivateGit\PadelTournament\PadelTour_Prod\Controllers\AccountController.cs:line 183 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Web.Mvc.Async.TaskAsyncActionDescriptor.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass8_0.<BeginInvokeAsynchronousActionMethod>b__1(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass11_0.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__0() at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass11_2.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__2() at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass7_0.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__1(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass3_6.b__4() at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass3_1.b__1(IAsyncResult asyncResult) ClientConnectionId:ec35cfdd-853f-4f17-92ca-8fde794ee5f7 Error Number:262,State:1,Class:14

Anyone has any ideas about how to go about this?

Comment: Curious why you started a new website with MVC 5 rather than ASP.NET Core MVC?

Comment: As for your create database error...what's the stack trace?

Comment: I've added the entire stack trace to the original post @mason

And regarding the .NET Core vs normal Framework, not sure to be honest, probably just out of old habit.

Comment: Don't let old habit keep you stuck in the past. ASP.NET MVC 5 came out in 2013. In the years since, ASP.NET Core is faster, more secure, more pleasant to work with, supported by more modern libraries, and the direction everything is moving. There's really not a good reason to start a new ASP.NET MVC 5 project in 2022.

Comment: Looks like AccountController line 183 is the last line of your code that's in this stack, though it's probably not doing anything too interesting. Did you check to verify that 1) the database exists 2) that the connection string used by Entity Framework is actually correct 3) that the account that the DB is running under is able to see that database? I doubt Entity Framework would be trying to create the database if it knew that the database was there, so you need to debug why it think the DB isn't there.

Comment: Hmm, it should be. I've only changed the connection string from my local DB to the remote one in the web.config. And it seems to find the server as such. And the database name is correct.

Line 183 is just the ´await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);

Comment: You have to debug. Verify that EF is getting correct connection string, has proper permissions etc. When things go wrong, don't make assumptions: you test everything in the chain until you figure out which part isn't as it should be.

Comment: Of course and that's what I'm going to do now. I was just thinking that these might be some slight oversight on my part that others do all the time as well. :) But thanks for your input, I'll start the dig.